# How to disable highlighting of widget?

Tags: qt

In general I need to disable highlighting the QListWidget when user selects the item or widget receives the focus. But I think, that should be a common method for all widgets to do this.

Comment: Maybe `listwidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection)`?

Comment: do you want disable focus on widget (solution above)? Or widget shouldn't indicate that it has a focus (do not draw selection)?

Comment: @ Marek R - the second option

Comment: @vahancho - your solution just disables ability to select the widget content.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the palette for `Highlight` and `HighlightedText` roles. Just set the `Highlight` color of the widget to ‍‍‍‍`Base‍‍‍` and `HighlightedText` to `Text` :

```
QPalette palette;
palette.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, listWidget->palette().color(QPalette::Base));
palette.setColor(QPalette::HighlightedText, listWidget->palette().color(QPalette::Text));
listWidget->setPalette(palette);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, please look comment for vahancho answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean highlight of (whole) QListView Widget, you may change this property in forms editor or set this in code:

```
listWidget->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do the following:

```
QListWidget lw;

[..]

QPalette p = lw.palette();
QColor bgColor = p.color(QPalette::Window);
QColor fgColor = p.color(QPalette::Text);

// Set the item selection color to be the background color of the list widget.
lw.setStyleSheet(QString("QListWidget:item:selected:active { background: %1;} "
                         "QListWidget:item:selected:active {color: %2; }")
                         .arg(bgColor.name()).arg(fgColor.name()));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but need to disable highlighting of WIDGET, not widget items (list items). When user clicks on the lw, it becomes highlighted (at least on mac). Need to disable this behaviour.