# How to disable text selection in a QDoubleSpinBox?

Tags: qt, qt5, selection, textselection, qdoublespinbox

I want to make (or at least know If this is even possible) text that appears in `QDoubleSpinBox` to be unselectable. Right now, it looks like this:

[image: QDoubleSpinBBox with text highlighted]

I have managed to make it so that the `QDoubleSpinBox` can't be focused with `setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus)`. But this doesn't apply to the text in it.

Comment: Have you tried to search about this? And if so, what solutions have you tried (other than disabling focus), and how did they not work? [edit] your question to add that.

Comment: Related posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356673/how-to-completely-disable-value-highlighting-of-qspinboxes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892129/how-to-prevent-qspinbox-from-automatically-highlighting-contents, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885441/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-widget?rq=3, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973378/how-to-disable-selection-highlighting-in-a-qtablewidget?rq=3, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392707/disable-editing-in-qspinbox-but-enable-arrows?rq=3

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayeneMihoub Thank you for pointing related posts to me. I will look at them and try to find solution. If there is no solution in them I will edit my question with what I tried (So far It was only **disabling** **focus** and **disabling** **widget**)

Comment: @Veljko It seems like you're having an [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (aka: asking the wrong question). Can you explain why you want to prevent selection? There are many (possibly valid) reasons for not wanting that, but we can only guess *some* of them, and we cannot provide answers based on assumptions. Do you want to prevent clipboard usage? You don't like the selection color? You don't like the selection behavior (the selection trigger when using keyboard/UI arrows) or the cursor position change? Do you want to avoid selection on focus?

Comment: @musicamante There is some parts of my UI that I want to be read only (and this `QDoubleSpinBox` is one of them) and I want it to be clear to user that they are just for reading value. It is not critical if user tries to enter value when he possibly select text, but I don't want it anyways. In one hand It is true that my question is asked weirdly, but that is because this is not critical problem for my project but something that I encountered and wondered if there is work around. Maybe in the future I have same reasons you mentioned and want to know how to cut off similar widget behaviors.

Comment: @Veljko You should carefully consider user expectations (and standard conventions) when dealing with the UI. Your question is ambiguous because the question you're asking yourself, while it makes sense, is ambiguous in its nature; before asking how can the selection be disabled, you should ask: 1. the reason for which you want this; 2. what will the user think about this difference in aspect and behavior; 3. how this would affect user interaction. For instance, if you want to make it read only, you can use [``setReadOnly(True)`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#readOnly-prop), but »

Comment: @Veljko » that won't prevent users to be able to select the text, which may be something they would still want for clipboard reasons (and that's an important expectation); no input will be accepted (keys, mouse wheel) and the arrows will be shown as disabled, which is normally a sufficient hint; you could eventually alter the palette copying the `Highlight` role for the `Disabled` group (as long as you're not using stylesheets), which may be a further hint. You could even change the focus policy to prevent tab navigation (but still allow mouse selection). But it all depends on the *reason*.

Comment: @musicamante I already made it read only. I get what you want to say. Thank You for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can make the text unselectable by calling [`setEnabled(false)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#enabled-prop). But it will disable the whole QWidget (disable keyboard and mouse events). So, you should be more precise about what you want to disable and what do you want to keep enabled.

Comment: I am trying to avoid disabling it with `etEnabled(false)` and than changing palettes for disabled `QDoubleSpinBox`, but will keep that option if there is no other